# Get Marker from JSON file and show on GoogleMap

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I make a simple app get data marker from JSON file and draw them on GoogleMap.

I have get marker information from the file and added it to the list `allMarkers`.

But when I run my app, it only draw the map, not show marker and got a console notice:

`flutter: Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null.`

This is my full `main.dart` code

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future _future;

  Future<String> loadString() async =>
      await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
  List<Marker> allMarkers = [];
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _future = loadString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder(
              future: _future,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);
                allMarkers = parsedJson.map((element) {
                  return Marker(
                      markerId: MarkerId(element['id']),
                      position: LatLng(element['x'], element['y']));
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
            GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition:
                  CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060), zoom: 1.0),
              markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
              onMapCreated: mapCreated,
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
  void mapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      _controller = controller;
    });
  }
}
```

and my `data.json` (only for test)

```
[{
    "id": "8D5D-4CD323560F59",
    "x": 40.7128,
    "y": -74.0060
 },{
    "id": "E3E0D2C5-CB82",
    "x": 41.7128,
    "y": -75.0060
 }]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you are using Stack but you don't need as far as it seems.

Add condition inside the FutureBuilder always should be like my example down below.

There isn't return value inside the `FutureBuilder(builder: () => Widget)`. In your case, you are just doing some logic, you have to also return a widget.

Solution:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);
              allMarkers = parsedJson.map((element) {
                return Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId(element['id']),
                    position: LatLng(element['x'], element['y']));
              }).toList();

              return GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060), zoom: 1.0),
                markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
                onMapCreated: mapCreated,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Dear eset i can't use another widget because i'd use for first map so i create function  ,,,can u look at https://flutterforum.co/t/cannot-read-entire-file-to-parse-json/778 thx

Comment: I use this but it show circular progress indicator...

Comment: @Laraib.Sheikh, that means the data you return are NULL. Because the line `if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();` is equals to "Please show Circular ProgressIndicator if the snapshot doesn't contain any Data".

Comment: You can try code from this article https://medium.com/@mindful_midnight_camel_430/create-a-google-map-app-with-flutter-parse-markers-from-json-part-2-e19e1c1e270c